# Google OAuth request: Error 400: invalid_request Required parameter is missing: response_type

Tags: youtube-api, google-oauth

When I make an OAuth request POST to the Google OAuth endpoint I get a 400 error saying I am missing the response_type, despite clearly sending "response_type=code" in the request url:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube.upload&access_type=offline&include_granted_scopes=true&state=state1&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fauth.somedomain.com%2Foauth2%2Ftoken&response_type=code&client_id=12345465634-qle7u44c0j4hjdjvt1fakes9gju4qe71.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone receiving this error, try switching to an incognito browser window. and logging into an email address that you verified as a testing user during the oauth2 app registration.

This error seems to occur when you're already logged into a Google account which isn't a part of the testing list.

Comment: As difficult as it is to understand all of this to newbies like me, the only thing missing was that getting the Google token does not work if you are logged in to Chrome. Ridiculous. Thank you!

Comment: @IvanFerrerVilla yeah, that's what's going on. For some reason Google's oauth2 page retrieves a token for the account your _browser_ is logged into, not the one you're specifically logging into on the page. It takes way too long to diagnose this issue, it's not documented anywhere and I bet it's extremely common.

Answer (score -1):

The only thing i can see wrong with your is it your http char replacement.

I ran this with my client id and it works.

[https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload&access_type=offline&include_granted_scopes=true&state=state1&redirect_uri=https://auth.somedomain.com/oauth2/token&response_type=code&client_id=[YourClientID]](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload&access_type=offline&include_granted_scopes=true&state=state1&redirect_uri=https://auth.somedomain.com/oauth2/token&response_type=code&client_id=%5BYourClientID%5D)

Comment: I believe that is the next call as I don't have a token code at this stage.  I have also tried sending each parameter as separate query params.

Comment: Okay your right try this i tested it and it shows me a consent screen

Comment: OK, yeah it looks like it works when I just use a browser, but it fails from the platform I am sending from with a javascript related error - it's on my end.

Thanks for the help!